# Center Image inside div vertically using display table property

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I'm trying to center an image vertically inside the div. I've read few other similar questions here on stackoverflow and decided to use this solution:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="cell">
        <img />
    </div>
</div>

#wrapper {display:table;}
#cell {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
```

This works great for images smaller than the viewport size. Problem occurs when image is larger in height than the view-port. In that case wrapper div simply becomes the height of the image. And it overflows the page. How do I avoid that.

This wrapper div is part of view-port div. Viewport div is of fixed height and 100% width positioned absolute

```
#view-port{ height: 600px; width:100% }
```

---

EDIT: I think I caused some confusion regarding the question. I've created JSfiddle to explain what I mean

Here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/sublime/fgTtj/

I want to vertically center the image inside #outer I dont have image dimensions, as you can see on fiddle, it works perfectly, but when #outer divs height goes less than image height, say 200 it cuts the image. I want to instead shrink that image to fit the outer div

Comment: have you tried overflow:hidden? or is it completely making the div larger

Comment: This wrapper div is inside some view div of say 600px height. When image of height 900px comes in wrapper becomes 900px and overflows

Comment: I don't think you can do anything about this in pure `css`, `html`, because there is no way to detect screen height. Better use javascript for that.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen when the image has a larger height?

Comment: Do you know the dimensions of the images every time?  Or are these dynamic?

Comment: Image dimensions are dynamic

Comment: @m.spyratos: Actually I lied about screen, there is a div on top of wrapper which is of fixed width and height. But when there is a bigger image wrapper div height increases to fit that Image and it overflows that top div

Comment: @sublime: Better answer `Linus Caldwell` question, so we can help you...

Comment: Sorry for confusion, here is the fiddle for this :jsfiddle.net/sublime/fgTtj as you can see it is centered properly but as soon as you change height of outer div to be 200 it cuts the image

Comment: Of course it does because of `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: If you notice I've added max-height on image as 100% so I'm expecting to fit it inside the div. If I set max-height to 200px it will work, but I cant do that for practical purpose as the container size is unknown and depends on the screen size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer has been truncated and edited to meet the needs of the OP.

Using jQuery, here is what I would suggest.
You can get rid of several of your divs and just use a wrapper and your image.  The problem with your code above is that you gave your outer div a set height at 300px.  This means that it won't ever shrink smaller than that.  I've written a small script to account for the window size as well

http://jsfiddle.net/fgTtj/40/

I've set up your HTML like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src='http://s13.postimg.org/b7hmfvhyv/css.jpg'></img>
</div>
```

CSS like so:

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.wrapper img{
    position:absolute;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

and the new jQuery looks like this:

```
function center(){
    var imgW = $('img').width();
    var imgH = $('img').height();
    var half_imgW = imgW / 2;
    var half_imgH = imgH / 2;
    $('img').css({
        left: "50%",
        top: "50%",
        margin: "-" + half_imgH + "px 0 0 -" + half_imgW + "px"
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var wrapper_Height = $('.wrapper').height();
    center();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        console.log(wrapper_Height);
        var winH = $(this).height();
        var wrapH = $('.wrapper').height();
        if(winH <= wrapH){
            $('.wrapper').height(winH);    
        } else {
            if(wrapH <= wrapper_Height){
                $('.wrapper').height(winH); 
            }
        }
        center();
    });    
});
```

You can resize this window in any direction and the image will stay centered and not cut off.  This only works for one window at the moment, so you would have to adjust the script to accomodate more.

The awesome thing with this is that it will run in just about every browser, where `display:table-cell` does not work in older browsers such as IE6 and I think IE7.

Comment: This won't help as you said. I want to show the complete image without cutting it off or scrolling to see it. I just want to fit the wrapper div completely inside mask

Comment: this might be simpler with jQuery if you are up for that?

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of the `display:table`? You could leave it blank (or use `display:inline-block`), and add an `overflow` property.

```
#wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
  }
```

If you want to be able to scroll to see the rest of the image:

```
 #wrapper{
  overflow:scroll;
   }
```

Comment: I don't want to hide/scroll the overflow. I want image to fit the div. and point of display:table is to center image vertically. http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Comment: Oh. Have you tried `<img src="whatever" height="100%" width="auto"> ` ? That should make the image fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the image to extend the viewport height, set the `max-height`:

```
#cell img { max-height: 600px; }
```

Comment: that does't help as view-port is of 600px and it does not change when #wrapper becomes 900. I did try min-height:600px on wrapper but that didnt work either. I think it has something to do with table display

Comment: Ok, I don't get it. What exactly should happen then? Do you want the image to have a max height of 600px?

Comment: Yes, I want max-height of wrapper div to be 600px. Which would mean image inside it would become 600px as well.

Comment: @sublime: You have to make your mind and clearly state what you are trying to do. It is better to know what you need, before posting a question. It will save everyone from the confusion. Good luck...

Comment: Does setting the `max-height` like in the update to my answer do the job?

Comment: No, after setting display: table, wrapper div does not listen to max height anymore

Comment: I did not set the `max-height` to the `#wrapper`.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, here is the fiddle for this :http://jsfiddle.net/sublime/fgTtj/  as you can see it is centered properly but as soon as you change height of outer div to be 200 it cuts the image